# Java method that returns reachable objects

Tags: java, ruby, jvm, yarv

Is there a  Java equivalent for following Ruby method ?

**ObjectSpace.reachable_objects_from**: This method returns all the objects directly reachable from the given object.

Reference: Look for ObjectSpace.reachable_objects_from in the following document
http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/03/ruby-2-0-0-in-detail/

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that all Java programs are inherently multithreaded, and so to give an accurate answer to the question "what is reachable from this object", a Stop-The-World event would be required (as other threads may be mutating the object graph).

For inherently multithreaded systems, giving this level of power to a developer is a very bad idea.